# LeadConvert Troubleshooting

Tags: lead-conversion, debugging

How can you diagnose errors with the LeadConvert class?

I built this class out in a scratch org and it worked perfectly fine. I pushed that to a sandbox and now I cannot get it to work. I deactivated all validation rules on the lead, just in case, but I still do not get any real clues as to what the problem might be.

The logs of the Debug in Developer Console just say `FATAL_ERROR System.AssertException: Assertion Failed`

Here is the class:

```
public class leadConvert {
public void convert(Lead[] givenLeads){
    System.debug('leadConvert.convert class running...................................................');

    List<Lead> noOppList = new List<Lead>();
    List<Lead> withOppList = new List<Lead>();
    Set<string> emailSet = new Set<string>();
    //set<string> phoneSet = new Set<string>();
    Set<string> accountSet = new Set<string>();

    //Loop through and grab information to query on
    for(lead l: givenLeads){
        if(!l.IsConverted){
            if(l.Convert_No_Opp__c){
                noOppList.add(l);
                if(l.Email!=null && l.Email!=''){emailSet.add(l.Email);}
                //if(l.Phone!=null && l.Phone!=''){phoneSet.add(l.Phone);}
                accountSet.add(l.Company);
            }
            else if(l.Convert_with_Opp__c){
                withOppList.add(l);
                if(l.Email!=null && l.Email!=''){emailSet.add(l.Email);}
                //if(l.Phone!=null && l.Phone!=''){phoneSet.add(l.Phone);}
                accountSet.add(l.Company);
            }
        }
    }

    System.debug('noOppList = ' + noOppList);
    System.debug('withOppList = ' + withOppList);

    //Query contacts to see if a contact exists that should be used as the target for conversion
    //We also have to get the account of that contact for the conversion
    List<Contact> emailMatchList = [SELECT id, lastname, email, accountid FROM Contact WHERE email IN :emailSet];
    //List<Contact> phoneMatchList = [SELECT id, lastname FROM Contact WHERE phone IN :phoneSet];        
    Map<string,id> emailMatchMap = new Map<string,id>();
    Map<id,id> contactAccountMap = new Map<id,id>();
    for(Contact c: emailMatchList){
        emailMatchMap.put(c.email, c.Id);
        contactAccountMap.put(c.id,c.AccountId);
    }

    //Search for accounts that match company
    List<Account> accountMatchList = [SELECT id, name FROM Account WHERE name IN :accountSet];
    Map<string,id> accountMatchMap = new Map<string,id>();
    for(Account a: accountMatchList){
        accountMatchMap.put(a.name, a.id);
    }

    //List used to convert
    List<Database.LeadConvert> leadConvertList = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();

    //Add to convert list without an opportunity
    for(lead lno: noOppList){
        Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(lno.Id);
        lc.convertedstatus = 'Conditionally Enrolled';
        lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true); //the only difference betweeen the two for loops
        if(lno.Email!=null && lno.Email!=''){
            if(emailMatchMap.containsKey(lno.Email) && emailMatchMap.get(lno.Email)!=null){
                id contactID = emailMatchMap.get(lno.Email);
                if(contactAccountMap.containsKey(contactID) && contactAccountMap.get(contactID)!=null){
                    lc.setAccountId(contactAccountMap.get(contactID));
                    lc.setContactId(contactID);
                }
            }
        }
        if(lc.accountid == null){
            if(accountMatchMap.containsKey(lno.Company) && accountMatchMap.get(lno.Company)!=null){
                lc.setAccountId(accountMatchMap.get(lno.Company));
            }
        }
        leadConvertList.add(lc);
    }

    //Add to convert list with an opportunity
    for(lead lyes: withOppList){
        Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(lyes.Id);
        lc.convertedstatus = 'Conditionally Enrolled';
        lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(false); //the only difference betweeen the two for loops
        if(lyes.Email!=null && lyes.Email!=''){
            if(emailMatchMap.containsKey(lyes.Email) && emailMatchMap.get(lyes.Email)!=null){
                id contactID = emailMatchMap.get(lyes.Email);
                if(contactAccountMap.containsKey(contactID) && contactAccountMap.get(contactID)!=null){
                    lc.setAccountId(contactAccountMap.get(contactID));
                    lc.setContactId(contactID);
                }
            }
        }
        if(lc.accountid == null){
            if(accountMatchMap.containsKey(lyes.Company) && accountMatchMap.get(lyes.Company)!=null){
                lc.setAccountId(accountMatchMap.get(lyes.Company));
            }
        }
        leadConvertList.add(lc);
    }

    system.debug('leadConvertList = ' + leadConvertList);

    //update the leads
    //LeadConvert can only handle 100 records at a time
    if(!leadConvertList.isEmpty()){
        //Update Opp close date with map of data
        Map<id,id> leadOppMap = new Map<id,id>();
        List<Opportunity> updateOppList = new List<Opportunity>();

        //convert the leads
        for(Integer i = 0; i <= leadConvertList.size()/100 ; i++){
            list<Database.LeadConvert> tempList = new list<Database.LeadConvert>();
            Integer startIndex = i*100;
            Integer endIndex = ((startIndex+100) < leadConvertList.size()) ? startIndex+100: leadConvertList.size();
            for(Integer j=startIndex;j<endIndex;j++){
                tempList.add(leadConvertList[j]);
            }
            system.debug('tempList conversion = ' + tempList);
            Database.LeadConvertResult[] lcrList = Database.convertLead(tempList, false);                
            for(Database.LeadConvertResult lcr : lcrList){
                System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
                leadOppMap.put(lcr.getLeadId(),lcr.getOpportunityId());
            }                    
        }

        //after convert, update any opportunities
        for(Lead l: givenLeads){
            if(leadOppMap.containsKey(l.Id) && leadOppMap.get(l.Id)!=null){
                updateOppList.add(new Opportunity(id = leadOppMap.get(l.Id),
                                                  //CloseDate = l.ExpectedStartDate__c,
                                                  name = l.LastName + ' New Enrollement'
                                                  //type
                                                  //record type
                                                 ));                    
            }
        }

        //update opportunities
        if(updateOppList.size()>0){
            System.debug('Inserting updateOppList: ' + updateOppList);
            Database.SaveResult[] oppDML = Database.update(updateOppList,false);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can use `getErrors()` method to identify the issue.

Comment: Thank you. That method is not in the documentation!

Comment: doc is here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_database_leadconvertresult.htm?search_text=leadconvertresult